# NativeScript / Angular nested routing issue with clearing history

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an issue with routing in NativeScript 3.4 that drives me nuts. The idea of this test [project](https://github.com/abhayastudios/routing) is that the root app component is using a `<page-router-outlet>` and then using nested angular routing using `<router-outlet>` it loads a login parent and child, through which I am navigating to a main page which has two child routes.

If I route from the `login.child.ts` to the main parent/child with `this.router.navigate(['/main']);` then everything works fine and I continue alternating between the two children.

However, if I route to the main with clearing history `this.router.navigate(['/main'],{ clearHistory: true });`, which is what I want because after login I don’t want the user to be able to “go back” to the login, then I am correctly reaching the main parent with the first child, but then am unable to navigate to the other child.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

This is the routing I am using:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginParent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "loginchild", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "loginchild", component: LoginChild },
    ]
  },
  { path: "main", component: MainParent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "mainchild", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "mainchild", component: MainChild },
      { path: "otherchild", component: OtherChild },
    ]
  }
];
```

**Edit**: when I wrap the main route in a component that contains a `<page-router-outlet>` like below then it all start working. It seems however a bit cumbersome. I would be happy to understand how this can be more neat (perhaps the changes in NativeScript 4 allow for easier handling)?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginParent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "loginchild", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "loginchild", component: LoginChild },
    ]
  },
  { path: "main", component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: MainParent,
        children: [
          { path: "", redirectTo: "mainchild", pathMatch: "full" },
          { path: "mainchild", component: MainChild },
          { path: "otherchild", component: OtherChild },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you create a playground demo ?